# LINQ Noob, how do I write this common query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm a long time dev, but still kind of new to LINQ. I'm OK when dealing with one set of object, but things get tougher when I need to pull from several sources, and I could use some guidance in getting what I need here.

I have three tables in my database, two related tables and one that holds the PK/FK to tie them together. So something like:

**Users**

- UserID
- UserName

**Surveys**

- SurveyID
- SurveyName

**UserSurveys**

- UserID
- SurveyID

I am using **EF** and so all of this data has been pulled into Objects.

So... what I want to do is return a List of all Surveys that are associated with a given User. So something like (pseudo-code):

```
// currentUserID = the UserID I need to get matching Surveys for
var surveys = from Survey where (s => s.SurveyID == UserSurvey.SurveyID && UserSurvey.UserID == currentUserID);
```

I assume I need to make a sub-query and use a Contains() or something like that, but I keep tripping over myself. Help?

Comment: What is `UserSurvey`?  Is it a many-to-many table?

Comment: Yes, it is. The Users and Surveys tables above are simplified, but the UserSurveys is really pretty much that simple. It just denotes which Surveys are Associated with which Users.

Comment: if UserSurveys is only those two fields, in your edmx file do you only have two EntityTypes (Users and Surveys)? If so I would agree with Henk.

Comment: I had an existing DB in place, so the EF team suggested that, instead of using the standard DB First approach, that I use a tool they created (EF Power Tools CTP1) which is supposed to follow the Code First model, but it builds that classes based based on the existing DB. I know that's confusing. But anyway, it didn't create an *.edmx file, instead it creates the Entity classes and the Map classes. Here is the link to the Power Tools... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
from us in UserSurveys
where us.UserId == currentUserID
join s in Surveys on us.SurveyID equals s.SurveyID
select s
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is EF you should be able to do `someUser.Surveys`.

Comment: I agree. But the guys who built the database (not me) didn't actually FK to anything. Everything is "uncoupled" so to speak, so when EF scanned the DB and created the objects, it didn't link anything together. I suppose I can go in and create those relationships by hand, which *should* be done, but on my tight time schedule, I just need to make it work for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database and entity model has all of your FK references you should be able to do something like this....

```
// currentUserID = the UserID I need to get matching Surveys for 
var surveys = from s in Survey 
              where s.User.UserID == currentUserID
              select s;
```